# Facebook dialog Problem in Device,Not Properly Showing in Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, facebook-graph-api

I Successfully Integrate Facebook in my App.Its also working fine on simulator and Iphone,With the dialog box.

But when i install facebook official App from Itunes in my Iphone.On share function it will take my App resources to that App.with the following pages.And when I delete Facebook Official App.Its again Works fine.

[image]

[image]

Any Solution???? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the following lines of code of function

```
- (void)authorizeWithFBAppAuth:(BOOL)tryFBAppAuth safariAuth:(BOOL)trySafariAuth
```

in Facebook.m :

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)] && [device isMultitaskingSupported]) {
if (tryFBAppAuth) {
  NSString *scheme = kFBAppAuthURLScheme;
  if (_localAppId) {
    scheme = [scheme stringByAppendingString:@"2"];
  }
  NSString *urlPrefix = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@", scheme, kFBAppAuthURLPath];
  NSString *fbAppUrl = [FBRequest serializeURL:urlPrefix params:params];
  didOpenOtherApp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fbAppUrl]];
}
if (trySafariAuth && !didOpenOtherApp) {
  NSString *nextUrl = [self getOwnBaseUrl];
  [params setValue:nextUrl forKey:@"redirect_uri"];

  NSString *fbAppUrl = [FBRequest serializeURL:loginDialogURL params:params];
  didOpenOtherApp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fbAppUrl]];
}
}
```

This will always show a dialog box to the user.

Comment: More description of the different behaviors here : [facebook SSO](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso)